# How to properly use fetch .then/.catch or async await - Currency Exchanger example

Tags: javascript, json, dom, async-await, fetch

I am currently working on a currency exchanger (typical learning execrise) and I have the following code where the actual currencyObj should be a fetch request coming from the apiUrl saved in there.

Really confused on where should I call fetch so my code works just as it does with the current object.

help please?

```html
const apiUrl =
  'https://api.currencyfreaks.com/latest?apikey=e4e6767e5e13430c8cd63326eb5e3fb3';

const currencyObj = {
    date: "2020-11-16 00:06:00+00",
    base: "USD",
    rates: {
        FJD: 2.1025,
        MXN: 20.336349,
        STD: 20916.771033,
        LVL: 0.656261,
        SCR: 20.85,
        CDF: 1966.0,
        BBD: 2.0,
        GTQ: 7.786253,
        CLP: 767.1,
        HNL: 24.3,
        UGX: 3696.82168,
        ZAR: 15.526441,
        TND: 2.7505,
        CUC: 1.000669,
        BSD: 1.0,
        SLL: 10085.707955,
        SDG: 55.325,
        IQD: 1190.0,
        CUP: 26.5,
        GMD: 51.79,
        TWD: 28.5,
        RSD: 99.34,
        DOP: 58.508651,
        KMF: 416.150217,
        BCH: 0.004048582995951417,
        MYR: 4.123,
        FKP: 0.756372,
        XOF: 553.686228,
        GEL: 3.29,
        BTC: 0.00006255436365166103,
        UYU: 42.850636,
        MAD: 9.141451,
        CVE: 93.4,
        TOP: 2.301076,
        AZN: 1.7025,
        OMR: 0.384976,
        PGK: 3.517495,
        KES: 109.213333,
        SEK: 8.668586,
        BTN: 74.664275,
        UAH: 28.13259,
        GNF: 9807.883035,
        ERN: 15.000453,
        MZN: 73.787512,
        SVC: 8.752042,
        ARS: 79.658459,
        QAR: 3.641,
        IRR: 21000.0,
        MRO: 357.0,
        XPD: 0.00042846,
        CNY: 6.6064,
        THB: 30.127423,
        UZS: 10380.0,
        XPF: 100.726636,
        MRU: 38.3745,
        BDT: 84.876019,
        LYD: 1.364025,
        BMD: 1.0,
        KWD: 0.3057,
        PHP: 48.107638,
        XPT: 0.00111421,
        RUB: 77.447967,
        PYG: 7035.735189,
        ISK: 136.804655,
        JMD: 148.13708,
        COP: 3635.333906,
        MKD: 52.154673,
        USD: 1.0,
        DZD: 129.0,
        PAB: 1.0,
        GGP: 0.756372,
        SGD: 1.346778,
        ETB: 37.75,
        JEP: 0.756372,
        ETC: 0.19727756954034326,
        KGS: 84.310146,
        SOS: 583.0,
        VEF: 248487.642241,
        VUV: 112.108539,
        LAK: 9280.0,
        ETH: 0.002227742072022901,
        BND: 1.349464,
        ZEC: 0.016342539630658605,
        ZMK: 5253.075255,
        XAF: 553.686228,
        LRD: 159.0,
        XAG: 0.04048747,
        CHF: 0.912085,
        HRK: 6.398472,
        ALL: 104.723123,
        DJF: 178.114046,
        VES: 535099.0,
        ZMW: 20.915079,
        TZS: 2320.123553,
        VND: 23120.946118,
        XAU: 0.00052895,
        DASH: 0.01331416094157746,
        AUD: 1.370784,
        ILS: 3.36845,
        GHS: 5.835288,
        GYD: 209.014465,
        KPW: 900.062,
        BOB: 6.89835,
        KHR: 4065.0,
        MDL: 17.128284,
        IDR: 14128.324,
        KYD: 0.833552,
        XRP: 3.702332469455757,
        AMD: 481.616228,
        BWP: 11.203597,
        SHP: 0.756372,
        TRY: 7.65,
        LBP: 1512.4119,
        TJS: 11.332955,
        JOD: 0.709,
        AED: 3.672967,
        HKD: 7.75339,
        RWF: 988.13928,
        EUR: 0.844089,
        LSL: 15.51,
        DKK: 6.288475,
        CAD: 1.31185,
        BGN: 1.652696,
        MMK: 1295.627668,
        MUR: 39.85,
        NOK: 9.139229,
        SYP: 1257.5,
        IMP: 0.756372,
        GIP: 0.756372,
        RON: 4.12002,
        LKR: 184.739147,
        NGN: 382.463,
        CRC: 614.369829,
        CZK: 22.312,
        PKR: 158.375,
        XCD: 2.70255,
        ANG: 1.79587,
        HTG: 64.080901,
        LTC: 0.016030779095864058,
        BHD: 0.377045,
        KZT: 430.244954,
        SRD: 14.154,
        SZL: 15.51,
        LTL: 3.224845,
        SAR: 3.7505,
        TTD: 6.788463,
        YER: 250.324978,
        MVR: 15.4,
        AFN: 77.020217,
        INR: 74.5379,
        AWG: 1.8,
        KRW: 1108.003452,
        NPR: 119.46311,
        JPY: 104.6705,
        MNT: 2849.392271,
        AOA: 666.396,
        PLN: 3.785677,
        GBP: 0.756372,
        SBD: 8.101947,
        BYN: 2.566859,
        HUF: 302.753256,
        XLM: 12.4741162088666,
        BYR: 25668.59,
        BIF: 1937.540488,
        MWK: 761.15932,
        MGA: 3956.383963,
        XDR: 0.704679,
        EOS: 0.4003202562049639,
        BZD: 2.016661,
        BAM: 1.655785,
        EGP: 15.623378,
        MOP: 7.99045,
        NAD: 15.51,
        NIO: 34.875,
        PEN: 3.6435,
        NZD: 1.454738,
        WST: 2.610655,
        TMT: 3.51,
        BRL: 5.462189
    }
}

// iterate to push on select options
const currencies = []
for (const currency in currencyObj.rates){
    currencies.push(currency);
}


// painting HTML File
const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

const containerDiv = document.createElement("div");
containerDiv.className='container';
body.appendChild(containerDiv)

containerDiv.innerHTML = `


<label for="quantity">¿Cuanto dinero quieres cambiar?</label>
<input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="100000000">

<label for="ogCurrency">¿Qué moneda tienes?</label>
<select name="ogCurrency" id="ogCurrency">
    
</select>


<label for="endCurrency">¿A qué moneda quieres cambiar?</label>

<select name="endCurrency" id="endCurrency">
    
</select>

<button id="exchange-button">Convertir</button>

<h2 class="message"></h2>
`

const ogCurrencySelect = document.getElementById("ogCurrency");
const endCurrencySelect = document.getElementById("endCurrency");
const quantityInput = document.getElementById("quantity");
const message = document.querySelector('.message');
const exchangeButton = document.getElementById('exchange-button')

// writing currencies in both selects
for (let i = 0; i < currencies.length; i++) {
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.setAttribute("value", currencies[i]);
    option.text = currencies[i];
    ogCurrencySelect.appendChild(option);
}

for (let i = 0; i < currencies.length; i++) {
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.setAttribute("value", currencies[i]);
    option.text = currencies[i];
    endCurrencySelect.appendChild(option);
}



exchangeButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    

    ogCurrencySelect.addEventListener('change', calculate);
    endCurrencySelect.addEventListener('change', calculate);
    quantityInput.addEventListener('change', calculate)


    function exchange (ogCurrency, endCurrency, amount){
        
    }

    function calculate() {
        const from_currency = ogCurrencySelect.value;
        const to_currency = endCurrencySelect.value;
        const amount = quantityInput.value; 

        
        
        const baseValue = currencyObj.rates[currencyObj.base];
        const ogCurrencyValue = currencyObj.rates[from_currency];
        const endCurrencyValue = currencyObj.rates[to_currency];
        const baseAmount = (amount * baseValue) / ogCurrencyValue;
        const endAmount = ((baseAmount * endCurrencyValue) / baseValue).toFixed(2);
        message.innerText = `Tu cambio de  ${amount} ${from_currency} son ${endAmount} ${to_currency}`
            
    }
    calculate();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

just updating my own code to have a testimony in case some beginner like me has the same q. Heres how I solved it.

```html
const apiUrl =
    'https://api.currencyfreaks.com/latest?apikey=e4e6767e5e13430c8cd63326eb5e3fb3';
  
  
  
  const getCurrencies = async() => {
      const response = await fetch(apiUrl)
      
      const data = await response.json()
  
      const currencies = Object.keys(data.rates)

        // painting HTML File
        const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

        const containerDiv = document.createElement("div");
        containerDiv.className='container';
        body.appendChild(containerDiv)

        containerDiv.innerHTML = `


        <label for="quantity">¿Cuanto dinero quieres cambiar?</label>
        <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="100000000">

        <label for="ogCurrency">¿Qué moneda tienes?</label>
        <select name="ogCurrency" id="ogCurrency">
            
        </select>


        <label for="endCurrency">¿A qué moneda quieres cambiar?</label>

        <select name="endCurrency" id="endCurrency">
            
        </select>

        <button id="exchange-button">Convertir</button>

        <h2 class="message"></h2>
        `

        // selecciono los elementos del html que me van a servir

        const ogCurrencySelect = document.getElementById("ogCurrency");
        const endCurrencySelect = document.getElementById("endCurrency");
        const quantityInput = document.getElementById("quantity");
        const message = document.querySelector('.message');
        const exchangeButton = document.getElementById('exchange-button')

        // creo y escribo en el hml las options del select de og y de end
        for (let i = 0; i < currencies.length; i++) {
            let option = document.createElement("option");
            option.setAttribute("value", currencies[i]);
            option.text = currencies[i];
            ogCurrencySelect.appendChild(option);
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < currencies.length; i++) {
            let option = document.createElement("option");
            option.setAttribute("value", currencies[i]);
            option.text = currencies[i];
            endCurrencySelect.appendChild(option);
        }

        // elijo el valor del elemento para pintarlo en el html

        exchangeButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            

            ogCurrencySelect.addEventListener('change', calculate);
            endCurrencySelect.addEventListener('change', calculate);
            quantityInput.addEventListener('change', calculate)


            function exchange (ogCurrency, endCurrency, amount){
                
            }

            function calculate() {
                const from_currency = ogCurrencySelect.value;
                const to_currency = endCurrencySelect.value;
                const amount = quantityInput.value; 

                
                // aqui iria el then??
                const baseValue = data.rates[data.base];
                const ogCurrencyValue = data.rates[from_currency];
                const endCurrencyValue = data.rates[to_currency];
                const baseAmount = (amount * baseValue) / ogCurrencyValue;
                const endAmount = ((baseAmount * endCurrencyValue) / baseValue).toFixed(2);
                message.innerText = `Tu cambio de  ${amount} ${from_currency} son ${endAmount} ${to_currency}`
                    
            }
            calculate();
        })

}

getCurrencies()
```